# why the Django rest framework ModelSerializer. create and ModelSerializer.validate not working properly?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am developing an authentication system for User registration through Django rest framework.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import NewEmployeeProfile


class RegistrationSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    '''
    We need to add the password2, as its not the part of the NewEmployeeProfile model. So, we need to make it manually.
    '''
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type: password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NewEmployeeProfile
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'employee_code', 'contact', 'dob', 'password', 'password2')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        before we save the new user, we need to make sure that the password1, and password2 matches. In order to do
        that, we need to override the save() method.
        """

        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': f'password must match..'})
        return NewEmployeeProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs:
            account = NewEmployeeProfile(
                email=self.validated_data['email'],
                first_name=self.validated_data['first name'],
                last_name=self.validated_data['last name'],
                employee_code=self.validated_data['employee code'],
                contact=self.validated_data['contact'],
                dob=self.validated_data['dob'],
            )
            account.save()
            return account
```

views.py

```
class UserRegisterView(ListCreateAPIView):
    create_queryset = NewEmployeeProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializers(create_queryset, many=True)
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = RegistrationSerializers(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            newUser = serializer.save()
            serializer = RegistrationSerializers(newUser)
            return Response(data={"status": "OK", "message": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(data={"status": "error"}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('Enter the email before proceeding'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, password=password, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user


class NewEmployeeProfile(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    employee_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'contact']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.email)
```

The problem is when I test the API in postman, it gives below output:

```
{
    "first_name": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "last_name": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

However, while testing POST method in POSTMAN, I have entered all data.

screenshot:

[image]

while troubleshooting I found that in serializers.py inside the "create" function I returned nothing. So, I added

```
return NewEmployeeProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Now when I test my API, the POST submition goes in to infinite loop, giving no output in the POSTMAN 'body'.

I guess, I haven't overridden the "create" and "validate" methods properly.

```
app.urls
from django.urls import path
from .views import signupView, UserRegisterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', signupView, name='signup'),
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    ]
```

project.url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('apii/', include('AUTHENTICATION.urls')),
]
```

new error:

```
Bad Request: /apii/register/
[05/Apr/2021 11:17:48] "POST /apii/register/ HTTP/1.1" 400 82
```

Comment: You have not entered the data properly. `first_name` != `first name`. Similarly other parameters like `last_name` and `employee_code` (notice space vs underscore).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Thank you for your suggestion, I did that correction. But what am  I suppose to return in 'create'  function?. The current 'return' is taking the API into infinite loop as I have pointed out in my original post. If I remove "return NewEmployeeProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)" , I am getting same message in POSTMAN

Comment: why are you creating a new instance of `NewEmployeeProfile` in `validate` method?

Comment: because I want to create a new instance of an new employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue is with the keys you sent in request in the postman

I believe it should be `first_name` and `last_name` instead of `first name` and `last name` respectively.

Comment: the issue is resolved as per suggestion by Abdul and Crash

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data["password"] = make_password(validated_data["password"])
    super().create(validated_data)

def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs.get("password") != attrs.pop("password2"):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": f"password must match.."})
    return super().validate(attrs)
```

Also, the keys for first name & last name in form data must be **first_name** and **last_name**.

Update #1:

```py
def create(self, validated_data):
    validated_data["password"] = make_password(validated_data["password"])
    return super().create(validated_data) # forgot the return here.

def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs.get("password") != attrs.pop("password2"):
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": f"password must match.."})
    return super().validate(attrs)

# Also update the view
class UserRegisterView(ListCreateAPIView):
    create_queryset = NewEmployeeProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializers
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]

    # A custom create method is not required
```

Comment: Thank you again for your suggestion. I modified the function as you have written above, but I do not see any changes. however, the CMD prompt where my dev server is running. I see some error related to url routing. I have modified my original post with the urls.py content and the new error.

Comment: It says 400, what's the response in postman?

Comment: In the postman, I see   {"first_name":["This field is required."],"last_name":["This field is required."]}. This I have already mentioned in my original post.

Comment: Have you replaced spaces with underscores in the form data keys?

Comment: yes, I did, but my serializers.py has your latest suggested "create", and "validate". Therefore, "create" function doesn't have those fields anymore.

Comment: Control never reaches the create method. It fails at run_validators. Are you sure you're sending correct field names? Can you post the postman request as curl here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230746/discussion-between-user3521180-and-crash0v3rrid3).

Comment: @Crash0v3rrid3 also change OP's view and add that to your answer. That `post` method is not needed (the builtin implementation would handle it better), plus the `serializer_class` is not specified properly.